# Нужно ли заключить в кавычки слова: рококо, модерн, барокко?

Tags: кавычки

Нужно ли заключить в кавычки слова: рококо, модерн, барокко?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не нужно.Это устоявшиеся названия: стиль модерн, стиль барокко. Без родового слова  модерн склоняется: модерна, модерном, о модерне.